# Problems with implementation of exponentially ditributed Perlin Noise

Tags: c#, algorithm, noise, perlin-noise

I have been trying to implement an improved Perlin Noise algorithm [code](https://github.com/Ian-Parberry/Tobler/)[paper](http://jcgt.org/published/0004/02/01/) in `c#`. However, I get very weird results - even though I've looked my version of the code over again and again.
This is my noise function:

```
public static float sample(float x, float y) {
    float tx = x + 4096;
    int bx0 = ((int) tx) & 255;
    int bx1 = (bx0 + 1) & 255;
    float rx0 = tx - (int) tx;
    float rx1 = rx0 - 1f;

    float ty = y + 4096;
    int by0 = ((int) ty) & 255;
    int by1 = (by0 + 1) & 255;
    float ry0 = ty - (int) ty;
    float ry1 = ry0 - 1f;

    int b00 = p[(p[bx0] + by0) & 255];
    int b10 = p[(p[bx1] + by0) & 255];
    int b01 = p[(p[bx0] + by1) & 255];
    int b11 = p[(p[bx1] + by1) & 255];

    float sx = s_curve(rx0);

    float u1 = m[b00] * (rx0 * g[b00].x + ry0 * g[b00].y);
    float v1 = m[b10] * (rx1 * g[b10].x + ry0 * g[b10].y);
    float a = Mathf.Lerp(sx, u1, v1);

    float u2 = m[b01] * (rx0 * g[b01].x + ry1 * g[b01].y);
    float v2 = m[b11] * (rx1 * g[b11].x + ry1 * g[b11].y);
    float b = Mathf.Lerp(sx, u2, v2);

    float sy = s_curve(ry0);
    return Mathf.Lerp(sy, a, b);
}
```

Where `p` is a randomly sorted array of the integers 0 to 255, `g` is an array of 256 normalized random 2D vectors, and `m` is the first 256 elements of the set `1.02^-n`.

These are the kinds of results I'm getting (no extra octaves):
[image: noise map]

Would anyone have any idea where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There actually two mistakes I made:

1. The order of arguments for Math.Lerp is switched up, it should be `Mathf.Lerp(sx, u1, v1, sx);` instead of `Mathf.Lerp(sx, u1, v1);` for example
2. I'm rounding by casting to an integer - this causes problems with negative coordinates however. This should be changed to Mathf.FloorToInt (as I'm using Unity)

So, after these changes this is my (working) code:
public static float sample(float x, float y) {
    float tx = x + 4096;
    int bx0 = Mathf.FloorToInt(tx) & 255;
    int bx1 = (bx0 + 1) & 255;
    float rx0 = tx - Mathf.FloorToInt(tx);
    float rx1 = rx0 - 1f;

```
float ty = y + 4096;
int by0 = Mathf.FloorToInt(ty) & 255;
int by1 = (by0 + 1) & 255;
float ry0 = ty - Mathf.FloorToInt(ty);
float ry1 = ry0 - 1f;

int b00 = p[(p[bx0] + by0) & 255];
int b10 = p[(p[bx1] + by0) & 255];
int b01 = p[(p[bx0] + by1) & 255];
int b11 = p[(p[bx1] + by1) & 255];

float sx = s_curve(rx0);

float u1 = m[b00] * (rx0 * g[b00].x + ry0 * g[b00].y);
float v1 = m[b10] * (rx1 * g[b10].x + ry0 * g[b10].y);
float a = Mathf.Lerp(u1, v1, sx);

float u2 = m[b01] * (rx0 * g[b01].x + ry1 * g[b01].y);
float v2 = m[b11] * (rx1 * g[b11].x + ry1 * g[b11].y);
float b = Mathf.Lerp(u2, v2, sx);

float sy = s_curve(ry0);
return Mathf.Lerp(a, b, sy);
```

}